# Ruby On Rails: generate files on the fly in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, epub

**Update:**

After looking more closely into the issue I think I am understanding the problem wrong. Since epub is essentially a zipped file I have to generate files at some point.

The actual question would be how to do this efficiently in production if the number of files and file size I need to generate become large?

The ebook content will be generated from entries in the database as html files. I am thinking about storing those files with Amazon S3 but I am not sure if that's the best option out there.

*Original Question*

I am trying to create a web-based epub generation application with Ruby On Rails.

Currently I am looking into the eeepub gem: https://github.com/jugyo/eeepub.
I am wondering if there is a way to feed the epub content from database without declaring files as shown in the example.

```
  files [File.join(dir, 'foo.html'), File.join(dir, 'bar.html')]
```

There is an open issue regarding this:https://github.com/jugyo/eeepub/issues/17
from years ago....
I know the gem is very old and does not seem to be active at all. I have looked through the source code and still not seeing a solution. If anyone has any pointers on how to achieve this through eeepub or a better tool please help me out! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar requirement, did you find a good solution to this query?

Answer (score -1):

Hi @voidwalker You can check the best gems for e-publishing on [Ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=epub), here you can compare gems by their popularity and activity.

from this list I think the [Git-scribe](https://github.com/schacon/git-scribe) is the best gem as per your requirement. Please try it and let me know if it's helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Rails Guy thanks for the help! However I am actually not looking for a full-fledged ebook publication tool but a way to generate ebooks from database entries for a web app (sorry if I did not state this clearly). The tool you suggested is very cool though, will definitely put in my collection and try it out  in the future :)